# What do the p-values ​resulting from the SIMPER analysis in R represent?

Tags: r, p-value

I am doing a SIMPER analysis (in R) with the values ​​relating to individuals contacted in different reproductive seasons to see how the surveyed bird community has changed, and which species contribute most to this dissimilarity. I find everything clear, except the p-values. Do the resulting values ​​of the various "p" tell me whether the contribution of that specific species is significantly relevant in the total dissimilarity between the two monitoring seasons? Or do they indicate something else? Thanks

I find everything clear, except the p-values. Do the resulting values ​​of the various "p" tell me whether the contribution of that specific species is significantly relevant in the total dissimilarity between the two monitoring seasons? Or do they indicate something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question is about the [`vegan::simper()`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=vegan) function in R. When you request a permutation test it will randomly shuffle group labels and recalculate the contribution of each species to the dissimilarity under that new grouping. The *P*-value is the fraction of permutations in which the contribution was **larger** than in the observed sample, so this is essentially a hypothesis test for whether the contribution to the dissimilarity is equal across groups.

I do want to draw your attention to the following piece of that function's documentation (which was reworded somewhat in more recent versions):

> The results of `simper` can be very difficult to interpret. The method very badly confounds the mean between group differences and within group variation, and seems to single out variable species instead of distinctive species (Warton et al. 2012). Even if you make groups that are copies of each other, the method will single out species with high contribution, but these are not contributions to non-existing between-group differences but to within-group variation in species abundance.

Comment: Thank you very much @PBulls! And so, if "simper" results are not the best solution, how would you perform a dissimilarity analysis in R?

Comment: I don't know much about your domain of study so cannot provide more input there, perhaps you can check the Wharton 2012 reference? I just noticed that the method was very explicit about its shortcomings, I leave it up to you to decide whether a possibly bad answer might be preferable to none.